# Find out the number of months between two dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to calculate accumulating leave for personnel.
It grows by 1.25 days per month.
What formula should I use to add 1.25 per month starting from the date of employment?

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent article from Microsoft on this: [How to calculate the number of months between two dates in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214134).

I would like to show the steps you need to follow:

1. Enter `=today()` in one of the cells (say A1 Cell) in your spreadsheet
2. I assume that Cell A2 contains the Date of Joining for an employee
3. In Cell C1 enter `=(year(A1)-year(A2))*12`. This will give you the number of years the employee has served in months - (because we multiplied by 12)
4. In Cell D1 enter `=month(A1)-month(A2)` - This will give you any number of months that the employee has served less than a year (Ex: 1 yr and 8 months - so 8 months will be shown in this column)
5. Add the contents of the previous cells to get total months. In E1 enter `sum(C1,D1)`. This gives you the total number of months (completed months)
6. Now to multiply your 1.25 days / month in cell F1 enter `E1*F1`.

All this can be done in one cell using the following formula
`=((YEAR(A1)-YEAR(A2))*12+(MONTH(A1)-MONTH(A2)))*1.25`

Alternatively, use [the `DATEDIF()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-bd549d1c-f829-4691-a77d-4a1e3d42bc1a) as shown below
`=DATEDIF(A2,A1,"M")` - this will give the count of completed months

Comment: How would you calculate the leave fluctuation? If 2 days are taken for instance in the third month and 1 day in the sixth month

Comment: U need to be more descriptive in your question. Rather than comments, update your question with an example

Comment: But, @Jacques, please don't create [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Instead, try yourself now that you know what first step to take, and search and ask a new question if applicable.

Comment: John started 2015/01/01 and his leave accumulates by 1.25 days per month. So by 2015/08/01 he has accumulated 8 x 1.25 that equals 10 days. but through the period from 2015/01/01 to 2015/08/01, he has taken 2 days leave on 2015/05/15,16 and another 1 day on 2015/08/21. How would you calculate this in order to accurately monitor his leave without missing any fluctuation results?

Comment: Q2 - Where and how do I upvote your answers?

Comment: Yes, and another point I forgot... The adding of the 1.25 can ONLY happen when the exact day of the month has appeared. So if he started on 2015/01/15 the first 1.25 may only be added on 2015/02/15 and not at the start of month like on 2015/02/01

Comment: @Arjan Fixed the typo

Comment: @Jacques, you're working for a weird company. With that new rule, how would someone who is leaving your company ever be allowed to use their holidays? (And see http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Arjan looks like `=DATEDIF()` is not a built-in function. But I'm surprised to see the link you pointed out was a duplicate of something else. So mine turns out to be a duplicate of duplicate of duplicate (3rd order) :-)

Comment: They are allowed to use it, and I have to manually add and subtract their record whenever they take and when they get the new month's added. but it is cumbersome and a person can make mistakes by, for instance: Forget to add a new month's 1.25 to their total.

Comment: @Arjan - my bad. It was shown in the drop down list as I started typing the formula. I assumed it wasn't there. It exists. Agreed

Comment: =DATEDIF(C10,N11,"m")